# Querying on column which is not a part of a PK or a secondary index

Tags: cassandra

Please help me to resolve a confusion. [Cassandra book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491933666) Claims that attempts to query based on column that is not a part of a PK should fail (No secondary index for this column as well). However when I try to do it I can see this warning:

> Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING

Once I append `ALLOW FILTERING` to my query, there is no more error. I understand the implication on performance - however there is a clear contradiction to what is written in the book. Was this feature added later or book authors simply missed this?

Comment: I don't see the contradiction to the book - when you execute the query without `ALLOW FILTERING` it fails with given message. `ALLOW FILTERING` allows you to force execution, but frankly speaking query with `ALLOW FILTERING`, and without - are 2 different queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is great you have a textbook to guide you through important noSQL concepts, but don't rely on it as CASSANDRA is *open source* and is constantly updated by the community. Online resources such as the [official apache documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/) is a much better option to retrieve updated information / tutorials on new and existing features.

Although `ALLOW FILTERING` does exist, it is still recommended to use a different table construction (e.g. changing the column to a key) or create an INDEX to keep querying fast.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Cassandra has `ALLOW FILTERING` from version 1.

Also to explain `ALLOW FILTERING`,

As per the datastax documentation,

**Let’s take for example the following table:**

```
CREATE TABLE blogs (blogId int, 
                    time1 int, 
                    time2 int, 
                    author text, 
                    content text, 
                    PRIMARY KEY(blogId, time1, time2));
```

If you execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM blogs;
```

Cassandra will return you all the data that the table blogs contains.

If you now want only the data at a specified time1, you will naturally add an equal condition on the column time1:

```
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE time1 = 1418306451235;
```

In response, you will receive the following error message:

> Bad Request: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING.

Cassandra knows that it might not be able to execute the query in an efficient way. It is therefore warning you: “Be careful. Executing this query as such might not be a good idea as it can use a lot of your computing resources”.

The only way Cassandra can execute this query is by retrieving all the rows from the table blogs and then by filtering out the ones which do not have the requested value for the time1 column.

If your table contains for example a 1 million rows and 95% of them have the requested value for the time1 column, the query will still be relatively efficient and you should use ALLOW FILTERING.

On the other hand, if your table contains 1 million rows and only 2 rows contain the requested value for the time1 column, your query is extremely inefficient. Cassandra will load 999, 998 rows for nothing. If the query is often used, it is probably better to add an index on the time1 column.

Unfortunately, Cassandra has no way to differentiate between the 2 cases above as they are depending on the data distribution of the table.  Cassandra is therefore warning you and relying on you to make the good choice.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: The OP is asking why there is a difference in their book, not how `ALLOW FILTERING` works.